# Duplicating Empty Data in SQL when refreshing

Tags: php, html, sql

I've been working on a system that allows a user to insert data, which will pass into a MySql database using SQL querieshowever, I've noticed that every time the page is refreshed, empty data is inserted into the database. Connection, queries, PHP, HTML and every other code works. The redirection works as intended but I realise my system just needs a slight correction. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","system");

    $error = 0;
    $errormessage = "";


    if( isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha256' , $password);
    }else{
        $errormessage = $errormessage . "Please Fill all Fields";
        $error++;
    }

    if($errors == 0){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO User
        (name, email, password)
        VALUES
        ('$name','$email','$password')";

        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));

        $errormessage = "Data Successfully Entered";

    }

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<header>
  <div style="background-color:black"><div style="text-align:center;">  <h1><style="color:Black;">Register</h1></div></div> </header>  
  <style>

input[type=text], select {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align:center;
}

input[type=button] {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align:center;

}

input[type=password], select {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
align:center;
}

input[type=email], select {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border: 5px solid magenta;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
align:center;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
align:center;

}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

div {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 90%;
    border: 5px solid lime;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    padding: 20px;

}

</style>
</nav>
<div>
  <form method="Post">   

    <label for="name">
    <div style="text-align:center;"><input type= "button" id="RegisterPage" value = "Go to Register Page" onclick="document.location.href='example.php'">

    <input type= "button" id="LoginPage" value = "Go to Login Page" onclick="document.location.href='http://localhost/example2.php'"><p>Your Name</label><br>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required><br>
    <label for="email">E-Mail:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="At least 6 characters" required><br>
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Create your Account ">
  </form></div>

  <footer><div style="background-color:aqua; border: 5px solid black;">

  </form></div>
</footer>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with your insert statement to update the database records instead of entering more. Also, make sure to setup your primary keys in your DB.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO User
        (name, email, password)
        VALUES
        ('$name','$email','$password')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        name = `$name`, email = `$email`, `$password`";
```

Comment: Additional may clearer to mention, that one needs to set up a unique key to email or name or both.

Comment: There's a primary key with auto increment for attribute ID